# How to get real time frames per second from video file using MPMoviePlayerController without viewing video?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to show frames per second of videos which will be played on iPhone. I have stored all videos locally, and accessing them using `MPMoviePlayerController`.

Is there any simple function or any custom class available for `MPMoviePlayerController`, which can give me fps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no function within `MPMoviePlayerController` that reports the preferred FramePerSecond of the content.

You will have to go a little deeper and use `AVFoundation`.

See `AVAssetTrack`'s property `nominalFrameRate`.

---

From the [AVAssetTrack Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetTrack_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVAssetTrack):

```
nominalFrameRate
```

The frame rate of the track, in frames per second. (read-only)

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) float nominalFrameRate
```

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController *movie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];    UIImage *image1 = [movie thumbnailImageAtTime:0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionExact];
    UIImage *image2 = [movie thumbnailImageAtTime:2 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionExact]; You can also put float values to get frames in less than a second

Comment: @user731077 How is that connected to getting the **framerate** of a video?

Comment: @user91282 i am not talking about the frame rates this time. i just want to know that how can i get the common part in two different images.